# Did God dialogues with humans according to the quran?

Tags: quran, allah

Im a Christian, but I gain interest in the Quran thanks to God, for me it's the Last Testament and Most Holy Book that I have the opportunity to read.

God does not dialogue with humans. (You answer, He replies) 
Is this assumption correct according to the Quran?

I think that I've heard something about that assumption, I want to know if is correct preferably in an Arabic Quranic intrepretation.

Comment: Welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To make yourself familiar with our site and our model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not exactly sure what you are asking, God does communicate with His Messengers through various means, He spoke with some of them:

> وكلم الله موسى تكليما
>
> And Allah spoke to Moses with [direct] speech.
>
> <sup>— [Quran 4:164](http://quran.com/4/164)</sup>

> منهم من كلم الله
>
> Among them were those to whom Allah spoke
>
> <sup>— [Quran 2:253](http://quran.com/2/253)</sup>

Some of the means by which Allah communicates are listed in this verse:

> وما كان لبشر أن يكلمه الله إلا وحيا أو من وراء حجاب أو يرسل رسولا فيوحي بإذنه ما يشاء إنه علي حكيم
>
> And it is not for any human being that Allah should speak to him except by revelation or from behind a partition or that He sends a messenger to reveal, by His permission, what He wills. Indeed, He is Most High and Wise.
>
> <sup>— [Quran 42:51](http://quran.com/42/51)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

And Allah spoke **even with** persons, not mentioned as a prophet or a messenger:

*Or like him who passed by a town collapsed on its foundations.*

*He said “How can God revive this after its demise?”*

*Thereupon God caused him to die for a hundred years, and then resurrected him.*

*He said “For how long have you tarried?”*

*He said “I have tarried for a day, or part of a day.”*

*He said “No. You have tarried for a hundred years. Now look at your food and your drink—it has not spoiled—and look at your donkey. We will make you a wonder for mankind. And look at the bones, how We arrange them, and then clothe them with flesh.”*

*So when it became clear to him, he said “I know that God has power over all things.”*

[Chapter 2, ayah 259](https://www.clearquran.com/002.html)